# How to inject the whole root json object into a POJO property in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

```
class MyModel{

    @JsonProperty("first")
    public int a; 

    @JsonProperty(" ??? ")
    public String originalJson;
} 

void test(){
    var payload = """ [
          {"a": 1, "b": "xxx"},
          {"a": 2, "b": "yyy", "c": [1,2,3,4]}
    ]
    """;

    MyModel[] models = new ObjectMapper().readValue(payload, MyModel[].class);

    assertEquals("""{"a": 1, "b": "xxx"}""", model[0].originalJson);

    assertEquals("""{"a": 2, "b": "yyy", "c": [1,2,3,4]}""", model[1].originalJson);
}
```

I'm looking for a standard approach of putting original JSON part (as String or as JsonNode) into a particular property of the model object. Cannot find anything similar, because all annotations can address only contained property names/paths, but not the whole JSON object.

The closest thing I've found is a custom deserialiser, but still it's not clear how to use it in this case.

```
class MyModel{

    // not clear how to pass the whole object here, not a single field

    @JsonProperty(" ??? ")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = SampleDeserializer.class)
    public String originalJson;
} 


public static class SampleDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        final JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        return node.toString();
    }

    public Class<Object> handledType() {
        return Object.class;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to bind the root JSON object being deserialized to a particular property of the final instance?